# unable to correct fsck errors

Tags: fsck

I get a fsck error about every other time  boot up. I have booted to a USB and used GParted and checked the file system in question and it appeared to fix the problem but I still get the error. Would this be a sign of a disk problem? The problem is in the partion that Ubuntu is installed. Using 18.04 on a Dell precision computer.

Comment: Edit your question and show me a screenshot of the error(s), and screenshots of the `Disks` SMART Data window. Do you dual-boot with Windows?

Answer (score 1):

well , it "might" be  , but also filesystem corruption e.g. due to power cut  is possible

( you could give more detailed info on the hard disk/ssd type)

- check the output of `dmesg` on your console for errors
- see [if your disk reports errors via S.M.A.R.T](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-find-out-if-harddisk-failing.html)
- possibly [issue a S.M.A.R.T self test](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/SMART_tests_with_smartctl)
- possibly **run bios/uefi system internal hard disk test**
- check for **bad connections** to the disks
- check for **undervoltage** , especially on developer boards